# Errno -9996 Invalid output device (no default output device) error in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pyaudio, errno

I am trying to run this code and facing this error everytime.

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio as pa
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


CHUNK = 1024 * 2 
FORMAT = pa.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100 #Hz

p = pa.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input = True,
    output = True,
    frames_per_buffer = CHUNK
)

data = stream.read(CHUNK)
print(data)
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-164f54eaf929> in <module>()
     18     input = True,
     19     output = True,
---> 20     frames_per_buffer = CHUNK
     21 )
     22 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py in __init__(self, PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input, output, input_device_index, output_device_index, frames_per_buffer, start, input_host_api_specific_stream_info, output_host_api_specific_stream_info, stream_callback)
    439 
    440         # calling pa.open returns a stream object
--> 441         self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
    442 
    443         self._input_latency = self._stream.inputLatency

OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid output device (no default output device)
```

Also this line throughs the same kind of error

```
p.get_default_input_device_info()
```

Error Message is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-5040bbe021ac> in <module>()
----> 1 p.get_default_input_device_info()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py in get_default_input_device_info(self)
    947         """
    948 
--> 949         device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
    950         return self.get_device_info_by_index(device_index)
    951 

OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

PyAudio installed perfectly after this command

```
!apt install libasound2-dev portaudio19-dev libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 ffmpeg
!pip install PyAudio
```

But portaudio doesn't install anyhow.

```
!apt-get install python-gnuradio-audio-portaudio
```

This line shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-gnuradio-audio-portaudio
```

And `!pip install PortAudio` this shows

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PortAudio (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PortAudio
```

Comment: If you are using UBUNTU it looks like that is discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736238/how-do-i-install-and-setup-the-environment-for-using-portaudio)

Comment: I am writing the code in google colab.